# Spark: Passed function in java object does not work in spark environment

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

Writing my first spark program and finally have some basic stuff working but now they output isn't matching the data from the java program I am migrating.

The original Java program would go to a database and populate an Array with several years of data and I would then pass that to another object which would do several analysis and spit out the results, like averages but some datapoint are more complex so I can't just convert everything to Scala.

I have spark loading the dataset and I can confirm that it loads it correctly into my array for example

```
MyJavaOb{

int sales
int year

  int getSales(){
   return sales;
 }

}
```

And I have an array of these

MyJavaOb[] myArr

Which correctly loaded from spark

2016 , 500
2017 , 900
2018 , 700

But now I want to pass this to my analysis object that is a bit more complex. I'm only writing out one metric but I have a lot of them.

```
    MyAnalysisObj{

    final MyJavaOb[] arr;
     MyAnalysisObj(MyJavaOb [] arr){
      this.arr= arr;
    }

      getTotSales(){
        return getAvg(MyJavaOb::getSales);
     }

      getAvg(Function<? super MyJavaOb,Integer> x){
         int tot=0
          for(){
             tot = tot + x.apply()
           }
         return tot;
      }


    }

returns 0;
```

So for some reason in the spark environment the passed function doesn't work.  I can confirm the array values are present and it works in java but not in Scala.

Edit #1 Scala looks something like this:

```
scala> myArr
Array[your.java.object. MyJavaOb] = Array(your.java.object. MyJavaOb@123kghj,your.java.object.MyJavaOb@343jhhsa, your.java.object.MyJavaOb@834dsfd)

scala> val test = new MyAnalysisObj(myArr)

scala> test. getTotSales
Int = 0
```

Note: One subtle difference is that my object that is in the array is returned by a factory and what we operate on is an interface.  Not sure why this would be an issue though

Comment: What do you mean by "the passed function doesn't work" ? And could you put your spark code as well ?

Comment: Added some scala code to show where I reproduce the issue.  Not much to it.  The function does not work means that instead of passing the function to retrive the values to calculate the average it just returns 0.